# Sitecore context in HttpHandler

Tags: sitecore, asp.net-4.5

I have HttpTaskAsyncHandler in my sitecore solution and i call it I have sutup *IngnoreUrlPrefix* and etc.
By some reason i can't get access to SC.Context.Database Database is null in *ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)* method,
it looks like I don't access to Sitecore context in HttpHandler.

How to resolve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to access Sitecore Context (Database or Item) in the Handler. We have confirmed this with Sitecore Support for our task.

The best way is Implement a Processor in the Request pipeline begin.
How to Implement

Inherit HttpRequestProcessor in your class found in (using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;)

and add that Processor after SiteResolver in            < httpRequestBegin >

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" />
<!-- Custom Module  -->
<processor type="SND641.Customization.RobotsModule, SND641" />
```

Comment: Nice point as well I will try it. but I have fixed it with put   /            global::Sitecore.Context.Site = global::Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("website"); to handler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to ignore your script file (by using IgnoreUrlPrefix), then you it will not be processed by Sitecore's request pipeline and thus will not have a Sitecore context.

I think you can solve it by removing your url prefix from IgnoreUrlPrefix and make sure the file extension of your handler is added to the allowed extensions parameter of the FilterUrlExtensions pipeline processor:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
  <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx</param>
</processor>
```

This way you can call your script and still have Sitecore process all the pipelines.

Comment: I was confusing your handler for a generic handler (ashx file). I'll try reproducing it tomorrow if no one has answered it by then.

Comment: global::Sitecore.Context.Site = global::Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("website"); is solve my issue thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get context without pipeline. Along with web.config handler definition, you will need to add under customHandler. It helps in getting sitecore context. E.g

```
<customHandlers>
    <handler trigger="blogfeed.xml" handler="blogfeed.xml" />
</customHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I'm not getting exactly what you are trying to do. But by working with handlers I did have issues that my code was not able to access the sitecore object even when I updated the web.config  and

I noticed that my handler was like this:

```
 public class GetHandler: IHttpHandler
    {
      ...
    }
```

by adding the **System.web.SessionState.IrequiresSessionStatem**, like this:

```
  public class GetHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
    {....}
```

then everything started to work and I was able to get items from sitecore without issues:

```
Public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   Database webdb = Factory.GetDatabase("web");
}
```

previous my change the webdb was coming with nothing and the code was coming back with "Command "Sitecore.Database" is not valid"

after that changes, as I said, everything worked for me.

I hope this helps and adds some value to the existing answers.

regards,