# How to implement different content between different Sitecore Devices?

Tags: sitecore, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I need show different content between Default and Mobile devices. Is there any way to create a Language Version according to a Device? Or is it possible to create a handler or module where i can identify the current device type? Also, is it possible to create a custom `MediaRequestHandler` where I can identify the current device and change the `MediaPath` of the requested image?

This is my implementation of Pipeline Processor:

```
public class MediaToDeviceProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor 
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        HttpContext currentHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        if (currentHttpContext == null || Context.Database == null || Context.Device == null)
            return;

        var request = MediaManager.ParseMediaRequest(currentHttpContext.Request);
        if (request != null)
        {
            var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(request.MediaUri);
            if (media != null)
            {
                if (!Context.Device.IsDefault)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to create HttpModule and HttpHandler but there is now possibilities to get Sitecore.Device because it is NULL. Anyway, i've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040912/sitecore-context-in-httphandler and create a Pipeline Processor but Sitecore.Device is still NULL.  All i need now it is some extension which will be change the MediaPath of requested image.

Comment: How are you planning to structure your media library? Are you planning to have two identical folder structures of media items, then switch the root level folder in your MediaRequestHandler?

Comment: i would like to keep two images in the same folder with different names. For example, main_background.jpg and main_background_mobile.jpg.

Comment: So rather than showing different presentation of the same content for mobile devices, you want to show different content with the same presentation?

Comment: IMO relying on an item naming convention for media items as you suggest in your last comment, would not be a very robust solution.  I have added to my answer to describe using 'Versioned' media items as an alternative.

Comment: If you need to show different content, why not just have 2 different sites, one for web, one for mobile? If there is some shared content between both you can do that easily, but it all depends on how different the content will be.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question you could take a look at creating a custom device resolver.  Look at `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" />` in the web.config then use dotPeek to look at how this is implemented in Sitecore.  It's usually quite straightforward to replace the standard resolver with your own - you can inherit from Sitecore's device resolver and add whatever device detection code you want.  You *could* then set the language context in this device resolver.

For the mobile version of your site, are you using separate presentation components? If so, you could consider simply having a set of fields in your templates which are used for the mobile presentation components.

Regarding a custom `MediaRequestHandler`; I'm not sure this is necessary. If you had alternative content fields for media items, these would simply reference the mobile equivalents of your media items. If you use a different language for your mobile content, then this again would point to the mobile equivalents of your images.

**Edit**

If you choose to go down the route of having a different language versions of your content for mobile/default content you could investigate using the 'Versioned' media templates (based on `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File`) instead of the 'Unversioned' (based on `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File`).  There is a config setting which allows you to set the default which is used when creating new media items.  This would mean you could create a corresponding language version of your media items (uploading the different image) for the mobile site, you would not need a special media handler in this case.